# Apagar linha em arquivo html

Tags: html, log

Tenho um arquivo que mostra o horário e nome que um usuário fez login no site,
este arquivo é protegido por senha, existe alguma maneira de colocar um botão [Excluir] para excluir determinada linha ?

Eu uso o seguinte código

```
 $f = fopen("pass/index.html", "a");
    fwrite ($f,
    'Usuario: [<b><font color="#660000">'.$usuario.'</font></b>]
    IP: [<b><font color="#996600">'.$ip.'</font></b>]
    Data: [<b><font color="#FF6633">'.$data.'</font></b>]<br> ');

    fclose($f);
```

No arquivo fica assim:

```
 Usuario: [<b><font color="#660000">teste1</font></b>] IP: [<b><font color="#996600">xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</font></b>] Data: [<b><font color="#FF6633">07-07-2017 - 13:20:01</font></b>]<br>
```

> Usuario: [teste1] IP: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Data: [07-07-2017 - 13:20:01]

Gostaria que apos a hora tenha um [Excluir] para remover aquela linha.

Comment: Já pensou em usar [SQLite](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php)?

Comment: Estou usando uma hospedagem grátis, não e possível

Comment: Testa isto: https://github.com/bluelovers/txtSQL

Comment: Na verdade queria que o botão ficasse no próprio arquivo html

Comment: PHP não tem nada haver com HTML, PHP é back-end e HTML é front-end, você vai usar o txtSQL no back e vai criar um botão no front (html) que vai enviar uma requisição para o back-end (php) e o PHP vai executar o txtSQL e voilà.

Comment: hospedagem grátis com php, quem é?

Comment: Na verdade no arquivo fica assim Usuario: [<b><font color="#660000">teste1</font></b>]
    IP: [<b><font color="#996600">xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</font></b>]
    Data: [<b><font color="#FF6633">07-07-2017 - 13:20:01</font></b>]<br>

Comment: Seria interessante postar o HTML da página pois poderia facilitar e muito a busca por essa linha

Comment: Explica melhor esses arquivos. Um arquivo que salva os dados em outro arquivo? Ou é só um arquivo pra tudo?

Comment: A pagina de login salva a hora e node dos usuários  quando eles se conectam, quero colocar um "botao" [Excluir] apor cada linha para apagar essa linha

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sao dois arquivos, um que pega o nome de usuário e data e salva os dados em um arquivo HTML. esse arquivo HTML  e usado como "log", mas caro que para cada informação tenha um botão para excluir uma linha de informação .

Comment: Pelo visto o HTML é composto somente com essas linhas e mais nada. Veja a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

```
//parte do código que exclui uma linha caso seja passado parâmetro via get
if (isset($_GET['num'])) {

  $num = $_GET["num"];

  // lê todo o conteudo do arquivo para o vetor linhas
  $linhas = file("arquivo.html");

  //retira do vetor a linha excluida o -1 é para a linha anterior
  unset($linhas[$num-1]);

  //cria o arquivo novamente
  $arq = fopen("arquivo.html", "w");

  // insere todos os elementos do vetor sem o excluido
  foreach ($linhas as $conteudo){
    fwrite($arq, $conteudo);
  }
  fclose($arq);

}else{

  $ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

  $file="arquivo.html";

  //verifica se o arquivo existe
  if (file_exists($file)) {

     //conta numero de linhas para obter o número que servira de parâmetro no link excluir 
     $numLinhas = 0;
     $handle = fopen($file, "r");
     while(!feof($handle)){
       $line = fgets($handle);
       $numLinhas++;
     }
     fclose($handle);

   }

   $conteudo = "Usuario: [<b><font color=\"#660000\">$usuario</font></b>]IP: [<b><font color=\"#996600\">$ip</font></b>]Data: [<b><font color=\"#FF6633\">$data</font></b>] <a href=_altera_linha_arquivo.php?num=".$numLinhas.">Excluir</a><br>".Chr(10)."";

   //Escreve o conteúdo da variavel acima no arquivo
   file_put_contents("arquivo.html",$conteudo, FILE_APPEND);

}
```

> Você pode testar [aqui](http://kithomepage.com/sos/_altera_linha_arquivo.php). A cada refresh é criada uma linha nova com o devido link de exclusão